# Svg text size does not change for cellphone, no matter what

Tags: css, svg

I designed an svg text headline for a desktop monitor, but on a small Apple 6 and 7 cellphone (375x667) the svg text is extremely small.  I have tried many things to make it larger, but nothing works.  It looks great on a desktop monitor, but on the smallest screen sizes it's too small to read.

It's designed inline in the html code:

```css
#svg_head{
    grid-column: 6 / 16;
    grid-row: 3 / 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-family: camphorW01-Thin,calibri,arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 6%;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
 <div id="svg_head">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 750 450" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <style>
     .svg_head2 {
         font-family: roboto_thinregular;
         font-size: 13pt;
         font-weight: bold;
         fill: rgb(150,150,150);
         fadein 5s;}
 </style>

 <text x="45%" y="4%" class="svg_head2 fadeIn animate_behind"
 alignmentbaseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Very long SVG Text Goes Here,  About 60 characters long</text></svg></div>
```

I tried altering the text x="45%" y="4%" and I haven't found any combination that makes a difference.  I also tried some alterations on the viewbox, but no change so far.  Finally, I tried changing the font-size, and used other units like px.  That works on the big screen, but not on the cellphone.

The svg is responsive, and it's positioned correctly in all devices, but I don't want it so tiny on a cellphone that I can't read it.

Comment: Try with [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm checking it out now.

Comment: It looks like that's the answer.  May I ask you if that also works for d3.js?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with `D3.js`

Comment: Thank again @Zohir Salak - your idea was the right idea.